# Probability of picking exactly one ace?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Poker hand: **5** cards. Deck: **52** cards.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
52\\ 5
\end{pmatrix}$$

There is **4** aces, number of outcomes to pick one ace:
$$4*\begin{pmatrix}
52\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
And at last, number of outcomes to fill slots for other **4** cards.
**49** because, we don't won't to pick **3** remaining aces.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
49\\ 4
\end{pmatrix}$$

Result:
$$\frac{
4*
\begin{pmatrix}
52\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
*
\begin{pmatrix}
49\\ 4
\end{pmatrix}
}{
\begin{pmatrix}
52\\ 5
\end{pmatrix}
}$$

Can somebody explain why this answer is not correct?

Comment: Where do you get the 52-choose-1 from?

Comment: There are only $4$ ways to pick an ace. Further there are $\binom{48}{4}$ ways to pick $4$ non-aces.

Comment: Notice that since there are four aces, there are $52 - 4 = 48$ non-aces.

Comment: @drhab How only **4** ways? I don't get that part.

Comment: There are four aces in the deck: $A\clubsuit, \color{red}{A\diamondsuit}, \color{red}{A\heartsuit}, A\spadesuit$.  We want to choose one of them, so we only have $\binom{4}{1} = 4$ choices.

Comment: Do you get the part that there are $\binom{48}4$ ways to pick $4$ non-aces out of the $48$ non-aces? Likewise there are $\binom41=4$ ways to pick $1$ ace out of the $4$ aces.

Comment: I understand now everything. I was thinking about *outcomes* instead of *ways*. Thanks